# Get value from select array tag in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Last time i post my uncomplete question from my phone.
Now here is my complete question.
Okay So my problem is that i build an edit page **editProduct.php**. Here i build three forms as i have **Three Categories** Each Category have its own form. These three forms have almost everything is same.**e.g: Product Name input box, condition Select box and more**. i view product page when i click edit button edit page open and in a field it show the current value of product in input box and also in select box also in checkbox.**Here is my HTML Code.**

```
<input type="text" name="p_name[]" value="<?php echo $db_pname; ?>"  placeholder="Product Name">

 <select  name="guarented-delivery[]"  id="guarented-delivery">
      <option value="1 Days Shipping"    <?php if($db_gdelivery=="1 Days Shipping") { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>1 days</option>
      <option value="2 Days shipping"    <?php if($db_gdelivery=="2 Days shipping") { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>2 days</option>
      <option value="3 Days shipping"    <?php if($db_gdelivery=="3 Days shipping") { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>3 days</option>
      <option   value="5 Days shipping"  <?php if($db_gdelivery=="5 Days shipping") { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>5 days</option>
      <option   value="7 Days shipping"  <?php if($db_gdelivery=="7 Days shipping") { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>7 days</option>
      <option value="10 Days shipping" <?php if($db_gdelivery=="10 Days shipping") { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>10 days</option>
 </select>
```

Okay so this is the example, and i have three categories and each category form i use same code like this. i use **[]** with **name attribute** as it used in all forms so that it get value of all in array. but don't know **how to get the value of of selected or new text in input box? as it shows me the old value not new entered value.** Here is my php code.

```
$name = $_POST['p_name'];
    foreach($name as $pname)
    {
        $pname;
        // if i echo here then i shows me old product name 3 times echo outside this loop to get value 1 time.
    }
    echo $pname;
    //for dropdown 
    $gd  = $_POST['gdelivery'];
    foreach($gd as $gdelivery)
    {
        $gdelivery;
    }
    echo $gdelivery;
```

help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: A select has only one value. If you want more, then you need to give the multiselect attribute. Also no need for the brackets in the name. When you use `$color_name = isset($_POST['color']) ? (array) $_POST['color'] : [];` you always get an array you can iterate over.

Comment: Actually I am on my phone that's why I have not share my code completely.
I wants only one value. This select tag used 3 times in my form it also give me one value but as I ask before this is my edit page and I display old records here which automatically select old value of color but what if I change the value it won't change value but still displaying old selected value in a result by echoing. This is what I wants.

Comment: In that case you should have three different names. Each select a custom one. And then you can operate with 3 different Variables. For example "colors_cars", "colors_bikes", "colors_carpets".

Comment: That's fine but the code going to be too big but I want small and flexible which work on all three's, is their any way.

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean and posted an (tested) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing your comments, this will work for you:

Important is, that all selects must be within the same form.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="colors[]"><option value="black">black</option></select>
    <select name="colors[]"><option value="red">red</option></select>
    <select name="colors[]"><option value="gold">gold</option></select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$colors = isset($_POST['colors']) ? (array) $_POST['colors'] : [];

foreach($colors as $color)
{
    echo "$color<br>\n";
}

// black
// red
// gold
```

Comment: Hi, your code running well but not according to me. i want that i show me only that value that i select not other value. for example, as you define three select tags i select value from 1st select tag "Black" i give me only the value of 1st selected value not others. how i do that. this is my problem. Please help.And Thanks you so much for helping me.